# Enabling mailbox access auditing in Office 365 with MFA

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

Microsoft Security & Compliance center with Microsoft Secure Score has a long list of good, excellent and non-relevant security advises. Sometimes they seem a bit incompatible together...

Consider a situation where these are already done:

1. Enable MFA for Azure AD privileged roles
2. Enable MFA for (all) users

Then: **Enable mailbox auditing for all users** 
using O365-InvestigationTooling / [EnableMailboxAuditing.ps1](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-InvestigationTooling/blob/master/EnableMailboxAuditing.ps1):

```
#This script will enable non-owner mailbox access auditing on every mailbox in your tenancy
#First, let's get us a cred!
$userCredential = Get-Credential

#This gets us connected to an Exchange remote powershell service
$ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
    -Credential $userCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExoSession

#Enable global audit logging
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" `
    -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails `
    -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"} `
    | Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, `
        MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, `
        UpdateFolderPermission -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, `
        Create, UpdateFolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf `
        -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission, MailboxLogin, Create, `
        SoftDelete, HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems 

#Double-Check It!
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited `
    | Select Name, AuditEnabled, AuditLogAgeLimit `
    | Out-Gridview
```

However, `New-PSSession` fails with a Global Administrator account:

```
New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server 
outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : 
Access is denied.
```

I believe this is because the `Get-Credential` or `New-PSSession` doesn't support MFA. The documentation for [AuthenticationMechanism Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.authenticationmechanism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) doesn't seem to have such an authentication: changing `Basic` to `Default` doesn't help. Am I wrong?

Is there any other way for enabling mailbox access auditing for all users / checking its status?

Answer (score 1):

I was correct that the culprit was MFA alone. I **temporarily disabled MFA** for a Global Administrator account and the script worked fine. After all, you only need to do this once, or maybe occasionally just to update it for new mailboxes. Disabling & enabling MFA happens immediately, and for maximum (i.e. tin foil hat) security you can even change the password right before running the script.

UPDATE:  An **App Password** works, too! I'm not sure if that's really a secure choice from Microsoft, considering the information you could gain and the settings you could alter, totally skipping the MFA.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but to use powershell supporting MFA & Modern Authentication, you need to use the Microsoft Exchange Online Powershell Module - this can be downloaded from the "hybrid" section of the exchange online admin centre

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps